# XmlSerializer - Array in array

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I have the following xml file:

```
<ArrayOfX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <X>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <ArrayOfY>
      <Y>
        <Member1>1</Member1>
      </Y>
      ...
    </ArrayOfY>
  </X>
  ...
</ArrayOfX>

public class X {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Y> Y { get; set; }
}

public class Y {
    public String Member1 { get; set; }
}
```

But if i try to deserialize with XmlSerializer, Name contains the correct value but the Y list is empty. Any idea?

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( List<X> ) );
return (List<X>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class X {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ArrayOfY")]
    public List<Y> Y { get; set; }
}
```

With you class definition, if you try to serialize of a `List<X>`, the output would looks like:

```
<ArrayOfX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <X>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <Y> <!-- Not ArrayOfY -->
      <Y>
        <Member1>1</Member1>
      </Y>
      ...
    </Y>
  </X>
  ...
</ArrayOfX>
```

Your provided xml file is not a valid format to the `XmlSerializer(typeof(List<X>))`. It's expecting `<Y>` instead of `<ArrayOfY>` for the `List<Y>` member of X.

The attribute I added would instruct the serializer to look for an element with name ArrayOfY instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to populate the 'extraTypes' array parameter with typeof(Y).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx

Comment: I've already tried it: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( List<X> ), new Type[] { typeof( Y ), typeof( List<Y> ) } );, but does not work